# What are the differences of meaning between device, gadget, gimmick, and gizmo?

Tags: differences, synonyms

Further to [my earlier question about the words *off-the-shelf*](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/8249/2085) used in Time Magazine’s feature story titled “The Best 50 Inventions of the Year” (from the Nov. 11th 2010 issue), I found the following sentence in the same article:

> One analyst says the iPad is the fastest selling non-phone *gizmo* in consumer electronics history.

I understand there is some difference of meaning between *device* and *gizmo* / *gadget* and gimmick as a group. Are there great difference of meaning and usage between the *words* *gizmo*, *gadget*, and *gimmick*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A *gizmo* is

> a gadget, especially one whose name the speaker cannot recall.

Synonyms might be "thingamajig" or "whatsit" (colloquially).

A *gadget* is

> a small mechanical device or tool, especially one that is ingenious or novel.

Smallness is one of the defining characteristics, so a new type of earth-moving equipment is not likely to be called a gadget, however ingenious or novel it may be, but a pen that doubles as a voice recorder certainly would be.

A *gimmick* is merely a trick, usually used to attract attention or publicity. A gimmick does not have to be a mechanical device. This is the "black sheep" in your list.

*Device* is a bit broader:

> 1 a thing made or adapted for a particular purpose, esp. a mechanical or electronic contrivance : a measuring device.
>   • an explosive contrivance; a bomb : an incendiary device.
>   • archaic the design or look of something : works of strange device.
>
> 2 a plan, scheme, or trick with a particular aim : "writing a public letter is a traditional device for signaling dissent."
>   • a turn of phrase intended to produce a particular effect in speech or a literary work : a rhetorical device.
>
> 3 a drawing or design : the decorative device on the invitations.
>   • an emblematic or heraldic design : their shields bear the device of the Blazing Sun.

(Above definition taken from Webster's.)

Answer (score 4):

- *Gizmo* and *gadget* are interchangeable.
- *Gimmick* has a greater implication of uselessness.

Any of the three could be used to describe a feature of a product. The first two could also be used to describe the whole product. A *gimmick* could be an intangible or non-functional feature, while *gizmo* and *gadget* are more likely to refer to something tangible with an identifiable function of some sort.

Comment: Thank you for your correction. I admit I'm terrible speller. Yoichi